# Why we use Context API in ReactJs? What will happen if we use simple props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-context

My Question is Why we use Context API in ReactJs? I know the answer a little but the concept is not clear.
For Example, we have 4 components like (compA, compB, compC, compD) to pass data from compA to compD we use context API because we don't want to pass our data through in between components but we can achieve our goal by importing compD in compA and pass props from compA to compD. Then why we use context API?

Answer (score 2):

> but we can achieve our goal by importing compD in compA and pass props from compA to compD

From a code organization perspective, this only works if it makes sense that `compA` directly manages `compD`. Often, this is not the case.

For example, let's say `compA` is the whole application component, and `compB` is the header, and `compC` is a menu in the header, and `compD` is a menu item. It doesn't make sense for the top component to import every single little component that needs the top component's state; the top component would quickly become unwieldly huge and hard to manage.

Using the Context API allows for the separation of responsibilities without having to manually pass down everything through props.

Comment: ok Thanks means we can achieve by just importing but we are not gonna do this for code simplicity